# Excel Front end to Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, excel

Im working on a Line of Business web application that has a bunch of Excel lovers as its user base. It got me thinking that maybe it would be better to just allow the users to use the tool that they love rather than re-building the current web app that they dont love.
My question is, what would be the "best" way to go about putting an excel front end on a Sql Server db?

any thoughts/opinions are appreciated.
Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the users are (or can be) educated on the schema, you can pull the SQL table(s) into an Excel Pivot Table. See: [Connect to (import) SQL Server data](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/connect-to-import-sql-server-data-HA010217956.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a SSAS cube to your architecture and then allow the users to browser the data through pivot tables in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You could let them populate load/staging tables with excel data connections.  Anything other that that is probably pushing it.  I'm not sure how excel is with concurrency/performance/data integrity with multiple users.